# Expect object to have all given properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm writing unit tests for my Node.js application using Jest and I'm trying to test whether or not an API endpoint returns an object with a set of pre-determined properties. I have the following:

```
const sampleResponse = {
  "Game": "GameName",
  "World": "2",
  "Location": "ServerLocation",
  "Timestamp": 1516204557853,
  "alive": true,
  "time": 10.1,
  "min": 8.927,
  "max": 10.154,
  "avg": 9.409
};
```

I then used the following code to test for object properties:

```
test("Location for server cluster exists, and returns an array of objects", () => {
  return Request(Routes.LocationSpecific).then((result) => {
    expect(result[0]).toMatchObject(sampleResponse);
  });
});
```

Where `result` is an array of objects containing data similar to the above object, and I'm simply matching `result[0]`.

The test fails because the values for each object property returned from my API endpoint don't match the sample data above. The properties exist, the red appears in my terminal from the values not matching, but I'd like to get it green.

Is there a way to match all given properties of `result[0]` to a sample object, regardless of their values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compare the arrays of the keys:

```
expect(Object.keys(result[0])).toEqual(Object.keys(sampleResponse));
```